# Are these fruit flies really coming back to life after being frozen?

Tags: entomology, cryonics

I've found [this video](https://www.instagram.com/p/BZH3ZB4FwbI/) on Reddit where they pretend these are frozen fruit flies coming back to life... I didn't find any publication related to this specific experiment. Is this just a fake video?

Comment: ! froze grasshoppers in a jar for a few weeks ( home freezer 10 F +/-) .When slowly warmed to room temperature , they began moving.

Answer (score 3):

**Short answer**
Short-term freezing kills fruit flies. Long-term cryo-preservation of D. melanogaster is also not possible.

**Background**
Per a publication of [Koštál *et al*. (2016)](https://www.nature.com/articles/srep32346), long term preservation of insects is only possible for embryos, or larvae in diapause. Indeed, freezing is an effective way to kill adult fruit flies (source: [Phys.org](https://phys.org/news/2009-12-common-fruit.html))

However, D. melanogaster adults show very weak capacity to enter reproductive diapause, and larvae possess absolutely no capacity for diapause [Koštál *et al*., 2016)](https://www.nature.com/articles/srep32346).

<sub>**Reference**

[Koštál *et al*., *Scientific Reports* (2026); **6**: 32346](https://www.nature.com/articles/srep32346)</sub>

Comment: When I worked in agrocery store I was in charge of taking down the salad bar. Regularly, fruit flies would land on stick to the cold/frozen metal. When the salad bar was turned off, they would fly away.